# SQL basics - WHERE EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Yes this is for an assignment and I need pointers please.

I'm trying write a SQL query to list the veg_id, year and yearly yield of each vegetable that has been grown at any time. The following does not work in Oracle 11g. Can anyone help?

The tables are:

```
**PLOT**
plot#
gard_code#*
owner_id*
location
rent_code*
shed
water_supply

**Plot Usage**
plot#*
veg_id*
year
yield
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT veg_id, year, yield
FROM plot_usage
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT plot#
    FROM plot
    WHERE plot_usage.plot# = plot.plot#
    )
ORDER BY veg_id ASC;
```

Comment: What happens when you run your attempted query?

Comment: it displays everything

Comment: Do I have the syntax correct @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Hm, I'm still not clear why not a simple `SELECT veg_id, year, yield FROM plot_usage` would do it.

Comment: It's the 'at any time' clause that stumps me.. I assume that this means there must be a yield from the plot. A plot can have no usage so must filter that somehow

Comment: I'm keenly trying to learn this quickly :/

Comment: If a plot has no usage, I guess it won't exist in plot_usage, so no need to filter for that...? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten the table `plot_usage` in the second `select`

```
SELECT veg_id, year, yield
FROM plot_usage
WHERE EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT plot#
    FROM plot, plot_usage
    WHERE plot_usage.plot# = plot.plot#
    )
ORDER BY veg_id ASC;
```

Comment: Um, that would actually break the query entirely :)

Comment: Really? care to explain plz, so I delete after.

Comment: Hard to explain in a short format :) The `plot_usage.plot#` in the inner query actually references `plot_usage` in the main query, it wants to check if there exists a row in `plot` that matches the `plot_usage` in the outer query. Putting `plot_usage` into the inner query will make it compare to _all_ rows in the table, not just the current one in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You provided not enough information bout the schema design here, so I'll look into possible solutions.

1. `plot_usage.plot#` is a Foreign Key to `plot.plot#`. In this case all entries in the `plot_usage` have a corresponding parent record in the `plot` table we can consider them as a *valid* ones.

   Here you can use `INNER JOIN` with `plot` table, but as long as you don't require any columns from that table (and you seem not to), it is not required. Without it your query will be faster. So a very simple

   ```
   SELECT veg_id, year, yield FROM plot_usage;
   ```

   will do.
2. `plot_usage` is not related to `plot`. In this case you can have records that do not *belongs* to your *proper* data, therefore you might want to exclude them. In this case, go with the `INNER JOIN`, like in:

   ```
   SELECT veg_id, year, yield FROM plot_usage INNER JOIN plot USING (plot#);
   ```

Now, the condition that you've mentioned (“at any time”) means, that you do not need to filter your data. I assume, that `plot_usage` contains pre-calculated yearly aggregates based on some detailed information found elsewhere.